# Domain user is not retrieve in IIS after windows server changed to samba4

Tags: c#, iis, active-directory, windows-authentication, samba

My application uses Windows authentication in windows AD server, but now the server is changed to samba4.
Below code is used in the application to retrieve domain and username

```
string Domain_username =System.Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + System.Environment.UserName
```

It used to return  `DomainName\username` as expected.

After upgrading to samba4, above code retrieve the different results

output: `IIS APPPOOL\AppPoolName`.

if i try

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name
```

it worked but, I don't want to do any code changes because it applied to many places. what changes need to do in IIS or system to retrieve domain user

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you drill down through the various layers of IIS operation from your code layer to the underlying process threads you may well find more than one user name is returned as the current user at that level. If you want to keep your environment authentication as it is I think you may have to make the code changes.

Answer (score 1):

`Environment.UserDomainName` and `Environment.UserName` indicate the credentials that the *application process* is running with, not the credentials of the current user, which is why you are seeing what you are seeing. The only way this could ever give the user's credentials is if your application is using impersonation, so maybe it's that impersonation that broke.

Did you have to change your authentication when you switched to samba4?

Strictly speaking, you should be using `HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity` or `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` (which both should be the same) to get the credentials of the current user.